# Google Maps - Custom Tile Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps

I'd like to place an Overlay Layer on my Google Maps in Android.
According to the documentation I have to use a TileProvider, which is fine, but the  getTileUrl() function returns an URL, which holds and address to a image tile.

I'd like to overlay just a semi-transparent square. I'm able to achieve the result in Javascript, but can't figure out how to do it in Android.

My javascript code:

```
darkMapType = function() {
    this.getTile = function() {
       var n = document.createElement('div');
           n.style.cssText = 'background:rgba(60, 60, 60, 0.6);width:256px;height:256px;';
           return n;
        };
    this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
    this.maxZoom = 16;
};

map.mapTypes.set('dark', new darkMapType());
```

So far, my android implementation looks like this:

```
TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256, 256) {

    @Override
    public URL getTileUrl(int i, int i1, int i2) {
        // I just need a 60% black rectangle here
        return null;
    }
};

TileOverlay darkOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
```

I can upload a PNG image and then always return its URL. 
It is working that way, but i'm sure there is another way (the right way) to do it. Thanks. Also, the overlay is not visible during panning/zooming.

Comment: The TileProvider is intended to add an overlay based on location and zoom. Are you looking to make a purely static overlay that never changes while the user interacts with the map?

Comment: Yes, i just want to "darken" the Hybrid Map.

Comment: Create a custom extension to TileProvider then and return the bytes for your semi-transparent dark image.